# Boost::DateTime unable to parse correctly

Tags: c++, parsing, datetime, boost

I'm building a simple parser for a range of date input formats with VS2012, using boost::date_time. The problematic portion of what I have written is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/date_time.hpp"

namespace bt = boost::posix_time;

const std::locale formats[] = {
    std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m%Y %H:%M")), //25042014 23:59
    std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m%y %H:%M")), //250414 23:59
    std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m %H:%M")) //2504 23:59
    //additional formats removed for brevity
};
const size_t formats_n = sizeof(formats)/sizeof(formats[0]);

int main(void) {

    std::string input = "25052014 12:45";
    bt::ptime dateTime;
    std::stringstream ss(input);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < formats_n; ++i) {
        ss.imbue(formats[i]);
        ss >> dateTime;
        if(dateTime != bt::not_a_date_time) {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << dateTime << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that ss.imbue() doesn't seem to work this way for me, despite having searched for and found similar code elsewhere. I always get a not_a_date_time. It works fine if I replace it with

```
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m%Y %H:%M")));
```

but since I need it to cycle through the different formats that's not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to reset the input stream. So if the first one fails, it will keep on failing.

Here's the fix:

```
        ss.clear();
        ss.seekg(0);
```

Now, you will still have to fix the order of accepted input formats. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b389970e22d5242)**.

Consider writing a parser proper for this kind of scenario, since it will be tough to force the correct interpretation just by ordering the formats.

The streaming operations are probably best suited for fixed-format (de)serialization.

#### Full Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/date_time.hpp"

namespace bt = boost::posix_time;

const std::locale formats[] = {
    std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m%Y %H:%M")), //25042014 23:59
    std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m%y %H:%M")), //250414 23:59
    std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet("%d%m %H:%M")) //2504 23:59
    //additional formats removed for brevity
};
const size_t formats_n = sizeof(formats)/sizeof(formats[0]);

int main(void) {

    for (std::string input : {
            "25052014 12:45",
            "250514 12:45",
            "2505 12:45",
            })
    {
        bt::ptime dateTime;
        std::stringstream ss(input);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < formats_n; ++i) {
            ss.imbue(formats[i]);
            ss >> dateTime;
            if(dateTime != bt::not_a_date_time) {
                break;
            }
            ss.clear();
            ss.seekg(0);
        }

        std::cout << dateTime << std::endl;
    }
}
```